# Can I create a Vector with max size more then 999 elements? (get elem by index more than 999)

Tags: scala, vector, collections, seq

Can I create a Vector with max size more then 999 elements?
Precisely, I need to get element by index that is more than 999 elements?

For now, when I try it I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000000 is out of bounds (min 0, max 999)
```

code is: "pattern" consists of 100000 elements

```
def image(pattern: Vector[Char], patSize: Int): Vector[Int] = {

@scala.annotation.tailrec
def imageCalc(i: Int, caret: Int, image: Vector[Int]): Vector[Int] = {
  if (i < patSize) {
    if (pattern(i) != pattern(caret)) { //CODE FAILS HERE
      if (caret == 0) {
        imageCalc(i + 1, caret, image.appended(0)) 
      } else {
        imageCalc(i, image(caret - 1), image) 
      }
    } else {
      println(caret + 1)
      imageCalc(i + 1, caret + 1, image.appended(caret + 1)) 
    }
  } else {
    image.prepended(0)
  }
}
imageCalc(1, 0, Vector[Int]())
}
```

Comment: AFAIK vector doesn't have a size limit _(well your physical memory or Int.maxSize)_ but not so little like 999 could you share more code?

Comment: updated, somehow to get 1000 element as pattern(1000) is a problem for scala

Comment: Please show the code where you create `pattern` and call the `image` method, just to be sure that the `Vector` is really the size you think it is and that `patSize` really is less than the size of `pattern`.

Comment: sorry guys,  I was completely wrong! Vector is OK, I am not OK =)! One error was triggered when I created `Vector[Int](100000)`, another - forgot to increment `i`, at string `imageCalc(i, image(caret - 1), image)` So, I have made two mistakes at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most suspicious bit of this code is this line:

```
imageCalc(i, image(caret - 1), image)
```

In this code a value in the `image` vector is passed as the `caret` value to the recursive call. The `caret` parameter is then used to index `pattern` with no bounds checking:

```
if (pattern(i) != pattern(caret)) { //CODE FAILS HERE
```

My suspicion is that the first line should be

```
imageCalc(i, caret - 1, image)
```